# How can I add custom catalog attributes in Sitecore Experience commerce 9 and populate it with data from API?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api, commerce-catalog

I want to add new attributes for my catalog in Sitecore Experience Commerce 9 update 2 but not sure how to add it using the Sitecore Experience platform.
Moreover all the properties data need to be fetched and populated from an external API. What should be the approach to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this article for extending commerce entities (products, catalogs categories users etc.)with custom  properties
https://hachweb.wordpress.com/2018/07/15/sitecore-xc-9-0-2-walk-through-extending-product-definitions-with-custom-fields/
And this one for getting axcess to them within the engine 
https://hachweb.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/sitecore-xc-9-0-2-how-to-retrieve-composer-generated-templates-within-sitecore-engine/

Hope this helps you.

Best regards.

Comment: Great articles, but do you also know how to add custom fields from code (performing the steps the Entity Composer is taking, but not manually)?

Comment: Hi, thank you. From Code i only know that approach fom this article https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/083614 but i dont know if that is exactly what you mean

Comment: I've read that one, but I was hoping that the Entity Composer in 9.0.2 had some new approach.

Comment: Thanks @Christian this helped me with my first part of the question but the second part still remains. If I can retrieve any custom component value from the Commerce Engine then how the commerce Engine can populate the data with the data from an external API?